# if condition getting error in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

```
    //extract the link texts of each link element

    for (WebElement Page3 : linkElements3) 
    {
        linkTitles3[k] = Page3.getText();
        k++;
    }

    //test each link
    for (String t : linkTitles3) 
    {
            // Titles Click 
            driver.findElement(By.linkText(t)).click();
            System.out.println("\n"+ driver.getTitle());

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='d9c1cb30-3459-4246-919d-41c5fe23de2f']/div/div/article/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a")).isDisplayed())
            {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='d9c1cb30-3459-4246-919d-41c5fe23de2f']/div/div/article/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a")).click();     
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Thread.sleep(4000);  

                System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='d9c1cb30-3459-4246-919d-41c5fe23de2f']/div/div/article/dl/dd[3]/a")).getText());
                System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
                driver.navigate().back();
                driver.navigate().back();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No Teaching Notes Present");
                driver.navigate().back();

            }
    }
```

ERROR : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: **Unable to locate element**: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='d9c1cb30-3459-4246-919d-41c5fe23de2f']/div/div/article/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a"}

Comment: Friends, if condition working fine but Else throwing error that xpath in if condition is unable to locate

Comment: id seems dynamic. never use such dynamic ID to identify an element. the error says the locator (xpath) used, is not able to find the element. so try other locators. share the HTML part which corresponds to the element that you want to identify

Comment: Hi Naveen, I try all possible locators, its displaying same error. But now it is resolved just if/else wrap placed inside try catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `if/else` part inside try catch block. Because selenium will through exception if no element with given locator is available in the page.

```
try{
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='d9c1cb30-3459-4246-919d-41c5fe23de2f']/div/div/article/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a")).isDisplayed())
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='d9c1cb30-3459-4246-919d-41c5fe23de2f']/div/div/article/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a")).click();     
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(4000);  

            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='d9c1cb30-3459-4246-919d-41c5fe23de2f']/div/div/article/dl/dd[3]/a")).getText());
            System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
            driver.navigate().back();
            driver.navigate().back();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No Teaching Notes Present");
            driver.navigate().back();

        }
}catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("No Teaching Notes Present");
            driver.navigate().back();
 }
```

otherwise you can also use `isPresent()` instead of `isDisplayed()`